# Inserting multi select values into database codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

The data posted, including the multi select field is

```
Array ( [id] => 16 [pAttr] => Array ( [0] => Colour [1] => Size ) )
```

I am trying to insert an id with one attribute only and do it again in second row.

```
____________________
|  id  | attribute |
--------------------
|  16  |  Colour   |
|  16  |  Size     |
```

The controller method

```
public function add_config_product()
{
    $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
    $data['attribute'] = $this->input->post('pAttr');

    /*$data = array(

        'id' => $this->input->post('id'),
        'attribute' => $this->input->post('pAttr')
    );*/

    //print_r($data);
    $this->inventory_model->add_config_product($data);
}
```

Model

```
public function add_config_product($data)
{
    $this->db->insert('product_attr_value', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Controller:

```
public function add_config_product()
{
    $data['id'] = $this->input->post('id');
    foreach ($this->input->post('pAttr') as $attribute):
        $data['attribute'] = $attribute;
        $this->inventory_model->add_config_product($data);
    endforeach;
}
```

This will loop through the `pAttr` input array and add values in each rows.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass an array of values to a function in model to insert, then you can use the following type :

```
public function add_config_product($data)
{
   $this->db->insert_batch('product_attr_value',$data);
}
```